# Why do I get this error using AWS Marketplace GetEntitlements?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, aws-php-sdk, aws-marketplace

I am trying to interface my php code with AWS Marketplace. There seems to be no example in PHP, anywhere.

```
$client = new MarketplaceMetering\MarketplaceMeteringClient($config);
$request = array();
$request['ProductCode']=ProductCode;
$request['Filter']['CUSTOMER_IDENTIFIER']=$result['CustomerIdentifier'];
$entitlement = $client->GetEntitlements( $request);
```

I am getting the following error and don't know why?

Type: InvalidArgumentException

Message: Operation not found: GetEntitlements

Filename: /app/vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/AwsClient.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [MarketplaceEntitlementServiceClient](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/class-Aws.MarketplaceEntitlementService.MarketplaceEntitlementServiceClient.html) to interact with the AWS Marketplace Entitlement Service. It supports [GetEntitlements](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-entitlement.marketplace-2017-01-11.html#getentitlements) operation.

```
$result = $client->getEntitlements([/* ... */]);
$promise = $client->getEntitlementsAsync([/* ... */]);
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I should have used this  $marketplaceentitlementservice = new MarketplaceEntitlementServiceClient($config);

instead of the MarketplaceMeteringClient.